# How to re-write my T-SQL query to eliminate the "aggregate function on an expression" error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following query that is giving me a specific error message: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery".

```
 USE MyDatabase
 SELECT [MTH], 
        [RoomTypeCode], 
        SUM ([RN] * [AdultCount] / SUM ([RN])) AS    'Weighted Adult Ratio',
        SUM ([RN] * [ChildCount] / SUM ([RN])) AS 'Weighted Child Ratio'


 FROM PaxRatio

 WHERE [PropertyCode] = 'XYZ'

 AND [MTH] between '2015-07-01' and '2016-09-30'
```

The objective of the query is to give me the weighted averages of the AdultCount and ChildCount columns in my View Table (called PaxRatio).

I've tried with a CTE table rather than a VIEW Table but I am still getting the same error!

Comment: Side note: don't use [`BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  You should be doing "less than October", essentially (which will make dealing with leap-years much easier.

Comment: you're missing `group by` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only have to change the position of the brackets:

```
 SELECT [MTH], 
        [RoomTypeCode], 
        SUM ([RN] * [AdultCount]) / SUM ([RN]) AS 'Weighted Adult Ratio',
        SUM ([RN] * [ChildCount]) / SUM ([RN]) AS 'Weighted Child Ratio'
 FROM PaxRatio
 WHERE [PropertyCode] = 'XYZ'
 AND [MTH] between '2015-07-01' and '2016-09-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a `SUM` within another `SUM` function. You can instead calculate the `SUM` in a separate query and use `CROSS JOIN` in order to consume the computed value in your main query:

```
 SELECT [MTH], 
        [RoomTypeCode], 
        SUM ([RN] * [AdultCount] / sum_rn) AS 'Weighted Adult Ratio',
        SUM ([RN] * [ChildCount] / sum_rn) AS 'Weighted Child Ratio'
 FROM PaxRatio
 CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SUM([RN]) AS sum_rn
    FROM PaxRatio
    WHERE [PropertyCode] = 'XYZ' AND 
          [MTH] BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2016-09-30') t
 WHERE [PropertyCode] = 'XYZ' AND 
       [MTH] between '2015-07-01' and '2016-09-30'
```